# Pytorch CUDA out of memory persists after lowering batch size and clearing gpu cache

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm learning pytorch and practicing it on Dogs vs Cats competition on Kaggle using the kaggle gpu. I built a straightforward nn.

Here is my dataset:

```
class customDataset:
    def __init__(self, paths, labels, transforms = None):
        self.paths = paths
        self.labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype = torch.long)
        self.transforms = transforms
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.paths)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image = torchvision.io.read_image(self.paths[idx])
        label = self.labels[idx]
        if self.transforms:
            image = self.transforms(image)
        return (
            image,
            label
        )

labels = pd.Series(labels)
labels = labels.map({'dog': 1, 'cat': 0}).to_numpy(int)

trans = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToPILImage(),
    transforms.Resize([224, 224]),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])
cds = customDataset(pList, labels, trans)

train_ds, test_ds = torch.utils.data.random_split(cds, (20000, 5000))

dataloader = {
    'train': DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size = 1, num_workers= 2, shuffle = True),
    'val': DataLoader(test_ds, batch_size = 1, num_workers = 2, shuffle = True)
}
```

here is my nn, and fit function:

```
class Neural(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.seq = nn.Sequential(
            ## image size = 224x224
            nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size = 3, padding = 'same'),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size = 3, padding = 'same'),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            nn.Conv2d(32,32, kernel_size = 3, padding = 'same'),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            nn.Conv2d(32,32, kernel_size = 3, padding = 'same'),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            nn.Conv2d(32,32, kernel_size = 3, padding = 'same'),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(7*7*32, 112),
            nn.Linear(112, 2),
        )
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.seq(x)
        return out
    
def fit(model, loss_func, dataloader, optimizer, epochs = 10):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        running_loss = 0
        running_acc = 0
        print(f"epoch {epoch}/{epochs}", '-'*20)
        for batch, (img, label) in enumerate(dataloader['train']):
            img, label = img.to(device), label.to(device)
            pred = model(img)
            loss = loss_func(pred, label)
            
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            
            running_acc += (pred.argmax() == label).sum()
            running_loss += loss.item()
            
        print(f"loss at {epoch}: {running_loss/20000}, Acc:{running_acc/20000}")
        acc=0
        loss=0
        for (img, label) in dataloader['val']:
            img, label = img.to(device), label.to(device)
            pred = model(img)
            loss += loss_func(pred, label)
            acc += (pred.argmax() == label).sum()
        print(f"Val: loss - {loss/5000}, acc - {acc/5000}")

loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())

fit(model, loss_func, dataloader, optimizer)
```

After just one epoch I'm greeted with the error:

```
CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.90 GiB total capacity; 14.93 GiB already allocated; 29.75 MiB free; 14.96 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

I decreased my batch size to 2, and used `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` but the issue still presists on paper this should not happen, I'm really confused.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a bug. The only way to decrease your memory usage is to either 1: decrease your batch size, 2: decrease your input size (WxH), 3: decrease your model size.  I think you should look at the first two options as your 16GB card should be able to handle this network if you reduce your image size.

Even if you look at the size of your linear layer:

```
 size_gb = 53760*224*32*32/1e9 #layer 1, 2, float32, batch, /GB
```

This gives us 12.3GB, not leaving much room for your other layers.

Comment: Hey, I added a lot more max-pooling layers that reduced the size to 7x7 and reduced the batch size to 2. But still i have the same issue. I've updated my post with updated code as well. Do you find anything wrong ?

Comment: hmmm, it is a bit strange. do you know which line is giving you the issue?

Comment: have you checked your GPU usage with `nvidia-smi` to make sure nothing else is on the card?

Comment: I'm using a kaggle gpu so I can execute the `fit()` and `nvidia-smi`  at the same time. But it the memory seems to be full. Here is a thought, I'm I required to clear gpu memory after processing every batch ? I'm thinking if batches persist in memory, 20k images may add up easily 16Gb not to mention `labels` which are `tensor.long` by default

Comment: No, because by using a dataset/dataloader that should be cleared. What is `nvidia-smi` prior to training? If everything is set as you've said I can't see this model taking up more than 1GB... Does it crash instantly or does it take a few epochs?